# Roslaunching URDF cameras

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Currently I'm using fuerte on 12.04 ubuntu. I have been using cameras (with gazebo_ros_camera plugin) successfully. However for it to work, I had to modify the parser_deprecated.cc file :
from

```
  _sdf->GetAttribute("type")->SetFromString("depth")
```

to

```
 _sdf->GetAttribute("type")->SetFromString("camera")
```

Apparently parser_deprecated.cc only supports depth camera. My question is am I missing some other way to successfully use cameras (URDFs) without modifying parser_deprecated.cc ? Is there away to actually get the system to use parser.cc (instead of parser_deprecated)? Does depth camera also provide electro optical data as well as depth data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8/roslaunching-urdf-cameras/) by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7676 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

parser_deprecated will be fixed in the next couple days. Thanks for the input.

[SDF](http://robotsim.org/wiki/index.php/Sdf_format) is the preferred method to specify sensors, models, and other object in a Gazebo world. Files specified in SDF use the parser.cc class. However, ROS has no hooks for SDF.

The depth camera provides RGB and depth data. If more/different information is required, then we should create a new sensor based on a specification.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0